# VSCode Vim extension to search for visual mode selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vscodevim

In vim I can **search for a visually selected string** using a number of techniques including what can be found here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text

Is there a way to do the same thing in VSCode with the Vim extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, VsCodeVim doesn't support the  command in search mode, so that keybinding isn't possible.

If you want to see that in the future, opening an issue at https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues would help.

EDIT: https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search is implemented, so this functionality is now there.